# Convert Universal Windows app to regular app on VisualStudio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I am compiling an opensource microsoft project called [GLTF-DXViewer](https://github.com/microsoft/glTF-DXViewer), and when I load the code to VisualStudio, the code is presented as `(Universal Windows)`, some online reading yields that this app is supposed to be executed on all windows platforms and it has a generic interface etc etc...

When something is a `Universal Windows App`, it can only be executed directly from the folder `shell:AppsFolder`. Also, when it is being executed, eventually the executing process is svchost.exe, and not the original creating calling process.

For specific debugging purposes this behavior limits my application. Is there an easy way to disable the `Universal Windows App` behavior, and convert the application to a regular executable? That can be executed directly from any process with no overhead.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an easy way to disable the Universal Windows App behavior, and convert the application to a regular executable?

Currently, there is not such tool could convert UWP app to regular executable file. Even though, UWP app contains an executable file (.exe), but it need to rely on other files. And it  cannot be executed separately.

Comment: Even if I have the source code of everything? its not possible to just take the code to a different project and compile it somehow from there?, but still make the whole thing work

Comment: Your project type is UWP, so we could not compile it to other with Visual Studio. The better way is re-writhe the project.